# After login front end not accessible at same browser

Tags: authentication, redirect, routes, laravel-5

After login when I am trying to go to WelcomeController@index page it redirect me at admin home page (4th route).
my routes define

```
Route::get('admin' , 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin' ) ;
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
Route::resource('fdws','FdwController'); 
Route::get('/home', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'FdwController@index']);
```

I think this will happen because of middelware RedirectIfAuthenticated

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->check())
        {
            return new RedirectResponse(url('/home'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

One more thing welcome controller is for frontend no session,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the following line from WelcomeController's constructor, then you will be able access WelcomeController@index

```
$this->middleware('guest');
```

As written in the description, WelcomeController is configured to allow only guests by default

```
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Welcome Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller renders the "marketing page" for the application and
    | is configured to only allow guests. Like most of the other sample
    | controllers, you are free to modify or remove it as you desire.
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `$redirectPath` in your AuthController to redirect desired location after login.

```
protected $redirectPath = '/';
```

For after logout:

```
protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/auth/login';
```